# Is a good practice to combine multiple css classes when trying to create isolated components?

Tags: css, architecture, frontend, bem

I've been using for some time a "BEM like" syntax in my projects. Recently, I was just re-reading some CSS articles when I saw this: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#single-responsibility-principle

[image]

Basically, instead of putting all the styles of `header__button` inside that class, it also relays on styles from `button` class. Aren't we in this case coupling the *element* of **header** with the `button` class? That means that if in the future, we're gonna change the `button` class, we also need to remember exactly where we're using this class.

In this example maybe it makes sense because you're trying to have the same styles, but what about a layout component? For instance, let's suppose that I have a `Menu` class that position some children vertically, and I have a `Sidebar` class that's also going to apply some style to those children. And we use them like this:

*menu.css*

```
Menu {
}
Menu__item {
}
```

*sidebar.css*

```
Sidebar {
}
Sidebar__item {
}
```

*index.html*

```
<div class="Menu Sidebar">
  <div class="Menu__item Sidebar__item">
  </div>
  <div class="Menu__item Sidebar__item">
  </div>
</div>
```

If we don't put all the code about how to position items in the `Sidebar` class and in the future we change some of this code from `Menu`, maybe the `Sidebar` class is going to be broken. In the other case, if we repeat code in both classes `Menu` and `Sidebar` we're violating the SRP (single responsibility principle) discussed at the begging of the question. That's what lately, in my projects, I've been favoring code duplication, so I would write all the code needed for a `Sidebar` into the `Sidebar` class.

But, what would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a chapter which partially answers your question: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#external-geometry-and-positioning

In your example I'd day `Sidebar` should be responsible for `Menu` positioning but it shouldn't know anything about `Menu__item`s. And `Menu` in its turn should not know anything about its own positioning but should position its items inside.

If you really need to change something in `Menu__item` positioning when it's inside `Sidebar` use nested selectors:

```
.Menu {
}
.Menu__item {
}
.Sidebar {
}
.Sidebar .Menu__item {
}
```

Comment: You say "`Sidebar` should be responsible for `Menu` positioning but it shouldn't know anything about `Menu__items`", but your code does the opposite: `.Sidebar .Menu__item {}`.   
I think `Sidebar` shouldn't change anything inside `Menu` block. Only `Menu` knows about its structure.

Comment: That's true. First I said about the way it should be. And the last paragraph starts with "If you really need..." — it's about the way to handle such situation if you don't have another choice. Still in most cases you'd better avoid interdependencies of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should decide, what is it: menu or sidebar, and use one of these classes. If blocks are different a bit, you should use modifiers. If it is impossible to do this with modifiers, use two different classes.

Using modifiers:

```
// your menu
.menu { }
.menu__item { }

// your sidebar
.menu--some-modifier { }
.menu__item--some-modifier { }
//
.sidebar__menu {
    // set some styles (margins, positioning) for .menu
}
```

Two independent different blocks:

```
// your menu
.menu { }
.menu__item { }

// your sidebar
.sidebar { }
.sidebar__item { }
```